# Sencha touch 2.3 issue with hbox and textfield and textareafield

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I have created a layout in sencha using vbox and hbox layout.But the issue is when I uses textfield and textareafield ,its size remain same even though the screen size varies.

I searched a lot on google and found many having the same issue.

Code below

```
Ext.define('GS.view.RequestNew', {
extend : 'Ext.form.Panel',
xtype: 'requestnew',
requires: [
    'Ext.Label',
    'Ext.Img',
    'Ext.field.TextArea'
],
config: {
    title : 'Test',
    iconCls: 'favorites',
    layout:'fit',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            layout: 'vbox',
            items: [
                {
                    flex: 1,
                    layout: 'vbox',

                    items: [

                        {
                            flex: 9,
                            layout: 'vbox',
                            style: 'background-color: #A96D13;',
                            items : [{
                                flex: 1,
                                layout: 'vbox',

                                items:[{

                                    flex: 1,
                                    layout:'vbox',
                                    items: [{
                                        flex: 1,
                                        layout:'vbox',
                                        style:'background-color: #C48627;',
                                        margin : '6px 6px 6px 6px',
                                        items:[{
                                            flex: 1,
                                            layout:'vbox',
                                            style:'background-color: #C48627;',
                                            margin : '6px 6px 6px 6px',
                                            items:[

                                                {
                                                    flex: 1,
                                                    layout:'vbox',
                                                    items: [{
                                                        flex: 1,
                                                        layout:'vbox',
                                                        items:[
                                                            {
                                                                flex: 1,
                                                                xtype: 'label',
                                                                html: 'Source Location',
                                                                style: 'color:white;font-weight:bold;margin-top:21px;'


                                                            },
                                                            {
                                                                flex: 1,
                                                                layout:'hbox',
                                                                items:[
                                                                    {
                                                                        flex: 7,
                                                                        layout: 'fit',
                                                                        items : [{
                                                                            xtype: 'textfield',
                                                                            name: 'location',
                                                                            height: 45,
                                                                            maxRows: 10,
                                                                            maxHeight: 10,
                                                                            autoMaximize: true
                                                                        }]


                                                                    },
                                                                    {
                                                                        flex:1,
                                                                        style:'background-color: #FEDE65;',
                                                                        xtype: 'image',
                                                                        src: 'http://abc/resources/images/img_dropdown_icon.png'

                                                                    }
                                                                ]

                                                            }
                                                        ]


                                                    }]
                                                }


                                            ]

                                        }]


                                    }]

                                }]

                            }]

                        }

                    ]

                }

            ]

        }

    ]

} });
```

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: Have added my code @Akatum